# Apache fails to work/hangs when including mod_wsgi.so

Tags: centos, apache-2.2, mod-wsgi

I am running Centos 5 on 64 with apache 2.2.

When I include wsgi_module apache restarts ok with no errors, but it fails to serve any requests. It just says waiting in the browser when I access an URL.

Any thoughts of the problem or how can I narrow the problem down?

**UPDATE**

```
httpd -M
Loaded Modules:
core_module (static)
authn_file_module (static)
authz_host_module (static)
authz_groupfile_module (static)
authz_user_module (static)
authz_default_module (static)
auth_basic_module (static)
cache_module (static)
mem_cache_module (static)
include_module (static)
filter_module (static)
log_config_module (static)
logio_module (static)
env_module (static)
expires_module (static)
headers_module (static)
setenvif_module (static)
version_module (static)
proxy_module (static)
proxy_connect_module (static)
proxy_ftp_module (static)
proxy_http_module (static)
proxy_scgi_module (static)
proxy_ajp_module (static)
proxy_balancer_module (static)
ssl_module (static)
mpm_prefork_module (static)
http_module (static)
mime_module (static)
dav_module (static)
status_module (static)
autoindex_module (static)
asis_module (static)
info_module (static)
suexec_module (static)
cgi_module (static)
dav_fs_module (static)
negotiation_module (static)
dir_module (static)
actions_module (static)
userdir_module (static)
alias_module (static)
rewrite_module (static)
so_module (static)
dav_svn_module (shared)
authz_svn_module (shared)
bwlimited_module (shared)
php5_module (shared)
```

Syntax OK

Comment: What is in the logs? especially errors.log?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you are still loading mod_python into same Apache and mod_python was compiled for different version or mod_python was linking statically to Python.

This and various other issues that can arise are documented in mod_wsgi wiki.

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationIssues

Check that. Also ensure you set 'LogLevel' directive to at least 'info', instead of 'warn'. This will cause mod_wsgi to log more about what it is doing.

Comment: i was loading mod_python, but removed it. Still same error. Tnx for your response.

Comment: Double check you have removed it by running 'httpd -M' command to list loaded modules. Also ensure you do a complete 'stop' and 'start' of Apache and not just a 'reload' or 'restart' as mod_python doesn't always unload properly.

Comment: Added the loaded modules to the question. No python module loaded.

Comment: Next likely potential cause then is your application. Add 'WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}'. This works around problems with third party Python extensions that don't support Python sub interpreters.

Comment: BTW, I am just repeating stuff that is given in the documentation. You have read that haven't you? http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationIssues http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues

Comment: apache hangs when accessing any website hosted on the server, even the ones powered by PHP. I tried to read the documentation, but i could'nt make much of it ;)). Thanks for your help.

Comment: Disable PHP and try again. If it then works then the problem is that PHP is loading an extension module using shared libraries that conflicts with shared libraries required by Python. That or an extension module is using global symbols that clash with one used by Python in some way.

Comment: Does the /var/log/apache2/[access|error].log give any useful clue as to the module that hangs?